# Azure DevOps Rest API - List pull requests by tag/label

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any way to query Azure DevOps' REST API to return me a list of pull requests with a certain tag / label?

Been looking into the documentation here without much help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: which tag? git tag?

Comment: Pull Request Tag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20labels?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: so this not good? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20labels/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: @Mavi Domates Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help :)

Comment: Hey @WalterQian-MSFT - this is not the solution. What you're doing it filtering the PRs _after_ querying them; and not querying the PRs _with_ labels.

Comment: @Mavi Domates Currently, the Get pull requests API does not have such search criteria. I suggest you can  [create a suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) in the Developer community. I also update my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) documentation, we can add some search criteria in the URI Parameters, but currently label is not available. If you would like that feature, please use [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) and create a request for this feature. That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

As a workaround, we can filter the results of the API. Please check if the following powershell script meets your needs. I used [Get Pull Requests api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [Get Pull Request By Id api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) in my sample (Please change the commented value):

```
$organization = "{organization name}" // organization name
$project = "{project name}"  // project name
$repo = "{repo name}" // repo name
$pat = "{PAT}"  //PAT
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repo /pullrequests?&api-version=6.0" 
$pullrequestlist = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Method GET 


$pullrequestid = @()
foreach($prid in $pullrequestlist.value){
$childprid = $prid.labels | Where-Object{$_.name -eq "{label name}" } | select $prid.url  //label name
$pullrequestid +=  $childprid | foreach{$prid.url.split("/")[-1]}
}


foreach($prid2 in $pullrequestid){
write-host $prid2  
$baseUrl2 = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/pullrequests/$($prid2)?api-version=6.0"
$pullrequestlist2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl2 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Method GET
write-host $pullrequestlist2
}
```

Here is my result:
[image]